# plot raster and overlay point values that satisfy criteria

Tags: plot, raster, terra

I am plotting a raster like this one:

```
library(terra)
set.seed(1)
rr <- rast(matrix(rnorm(400, 1.5, 1), nrow=20, ncol=20))
plot(rr)
```

What I would ideally like is to add points to the plot where the raster values are above a threshold, the points I would like are seen here:

```
plot(clamp(rr, lower=3))
```

In my mind, something like this is possible (but in reality, this didn't work)

```
plot(rr)
points(clamp(rr, lower=3))
```

or maybe

```
plot(rr)
points(rr[rr>3])
```

obviously my examples don't work... anyone got an idea?

thank you,

m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
library(terra)
set.seed(1)
rr <- rast(matrix(rnorm(400, 1.5, 1), nrow=20, ncol=20))
x <- clamp(rr, lower=3, values=FALSE)

plot(rr)
points(as.points(x))
lines(x)
## or polygons 
# polys(as.polygons(x), dens=10)
```

So while `lines(x)` works, `points(x)` does not (this has now been fixed in the development version).

For this to work, the cells you do not want points for must be `NA`. Hence the `values=FALSE` in `clamp`.

To show different values (or ranges) for each point you can use `plot(..., add=TRUE)`

```
p <- as.points(x)
plot(rr, plg=list(shrink=.3))
plot(p, "lyr.1", add=T, legend=T)
```

Comment: Genius. Do you know the secret to colouring the points by their value? `points(as.points(x), col=x$lyr.1)` perhaps?

Comment: see expanded answer